# What exactly is the difference between an "attribute" and a "field" in MongoDB terminology?

Tags: mongodb, attributes, field, terminology

I've seen the terms "attribute" and "field" used interchangeably, and I'd like to know what the proper usage is. So far, it seems that "fields" are what's stored in the database objects, and "attributes" are key-value pairs used in client code, such as in `find()` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB documents contain key-value pairs, where each pair can be interchangeably referred to as a "field", "property", or (less frequently, but not inaccurately) "attribute".

Using "field" or "property" is probably best.

Comment: According to the [documentation on Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/), "MongoDB stores all data in documents, which are JSON-style data structures composed of field-and-value pairs".